# python program to print sum of consecutive numbers in a range

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, python-3.5

**write a python program to print sum of 3 consecutive numbers in a range in a list. for example we take input n = 8 so the program will print
[1+2+3,2+3+4,3+4+5,4+5+6+,5+6+7,6+7+8]**
means the output should be
=[6,9,12,15,18,21]
i am new in programming, my code is:-

```
arr=[]
N=int(input("enter the value of N"))
def lst(arr):
    for i in range(N):
        x=[i]+[i+1]+[i+2]
        arr.append(x)
lst(arr)
print(arr)
```

Comment: What do you think the result of `[i] + [i+1] + [i+2]` is?

Comment: [[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the output you are looking for. It starts indexed at 1 instead of 0 and calls `sum` on the lists you are creating in each iteration.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, creating these lists is unnecessary you can just do a sum.

```
arr=[] 
N=int(input("enter the value of N")) 
def lst(arr): 
    for i in range(1, N - 1): 
        x = (i) + (i + 1) + (i + 2) # for ease of reading 
        arr.append(x) 
        

lst(arr) 
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension - given a list and a length of interest `lgt`:

```
l = list(range(1, 9))
lgt = 3

print([sum(l[i-lgt:i]) for i in range(lgt, len(l) + 1)])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use list comprehension,

```
In [1]: [(i+1) + (i+2) + (i+3) for i in range(7)]
Out[1]: [6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24]
```